# How do I get the ID's back from a SQL insert statement, without another query?

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL database that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE gif (
    id varchar(32),
    filename varchar(32),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE tag (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tag varchar(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE gif_tag (
    gif_id varchar(32),
    tag_id int,
    FOREIGN KEY (gif_id) REFERENCES gif(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES tag(id),
    primary KEY (gif_id, tag_id)
);
```

I would like it so that when a user uploads a gif and gives it tags I insert it into the database as follows:

1. ```
    INSERT INTO gif VALUES('someUID', 'fileName.gif');
   ```
2. ```
    INSERT IGNORE INTO tag (tag) VALUES ('Kitten'), ('Skateboarding'), ('Rainbows');
   ```
3. ```
     INSERT IGNORE INTO gif_tag (gif_id, tag_id)    
    VALUES (1, "someUID"), (2, "someUID"), (2, "someUID"); 
    -- where 1, 2, 3 are the ids respectively assigned in step 2
   ```

Is there anyway that I can make it so that statement 2 will return the tag_id for each item so that I can use them in step 3?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe `RETURNING` can be used there?

Comment: Could you use last insert id in conjunction with a transaction